# andengine game- facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, andengine

Can any body refer me any tutorial on how to integrate Facebook SDK 3+ in a AND ENGINE Based game,i have tried it doing but it is not working ,i have a helicopter game based upon the architecture of **Matim's Tutorial Game** [Link to the Matim's game tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-1.html) , i have a main activity which initializes the engine and other thing and created BaseGame Class which is inherited by all the scene class ,i have a MenuScene Class which is used to display the play button and Facebook Login Button now I am using this tutorial [Facebook Integration with android](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/), i am able to login the user but when user is redirected back to game access token is not displayed i am using SharedPreference to store the accesstoken

My Code is as following-

```
public void loginToFacebook() {

    UserData.getInstance().init(activity);
    final String access_token = UserData.getInstance().getToken();
    long expires = UserData.getInstance().getExpire();

     ((BaseActivity)
             activity).toastOnUiThread("Valid-before"+access_token
             , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    if (access_token != null) {
        resourcesManager.facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        Challenge.setVisible(false);

         ((BaseActivity)
                 activity).toastOnUiThread("Valid-after"
                 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + resourcesManager.facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        resourcesManager.facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!resourcesManager.facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        resourcesManager.facebook.authorize(this.activity,
                new String[] { "email" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                        Log.d("Access Token", ""+access_token);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token

                        UserData.getInstance().setToken(resourcesManager.facebook.getAccessToken());
                        UserData.getInstance().setExpire(resourcesManager.facebook.getAccessExpires());




                        Log.d("Access Token", ""+access_token);

                            }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error
                        Log.d("Access Token", ""+access_token);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors
                        Log.d("Access Token", ""+access_token);
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Download the latest facebook sdk 3.5 and run the samples

Comment: have you solve the problem yet?